# Convert date string with AM/PM to javascript date object

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I would like to convert 'April 25, 2016 Mon 09:59 PM' to a javascript date object so that I can do some basic math on it. However, Date.parse() does not work producing Nan. I assume it's because Date.parse has specific requirements for formatting.

I cannot use any external libraries besides jQuery.

Comment: Are you sure the week day goes after the year on your format?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure. It's a result of some formatting on our engineering side, which is easier to compensate for than to get engineering time to get it fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to remove the date of the week using regex:

```js
var date = 'April 25, 2016 Mon 09:59 PM';
date = new Date(date.replace(/([0-9]{4}) .{3}/, '$1'));
document.body.innerHTML = date;
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct format would be:

```
var myDate=new Date('April 25, 2016 09:59 PM')
```

or

```
var myDate=new Date('Mon April 25, 2016 09:59 PM')
```

now you have a myDate object of type Date and you may access all the methods for the date object to do your calculations.

Comment: Yeah, but he has 'Mon' after the year, that's the requirement

Comment: Well the question doesn't state that as a requirement and even if it is a requirement it wouldn't be too difficult to strip the day out of the string and get the right format, would it?!